# Excel Macro to "Check-out" from OneDrive Sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, onedrive

I'm trying to develop a macro that has to "check-out" a sharepoint excel file, open with a preset password, update with some data from an offline file, save and then "check-in" back to sharepoint.

But, I'm stuck at very first step itself that I'm unable "check-out" the file and it throws the below error.

[image]

Macro Used:

```
    Sub ExcelUpdater()    
    FileSharepointLocation = Range("FileLocation").Value
    
    ExcelFilename = "Destination File.xlsb"
    
    FileAddress = FileSharepointLocation + "/" + ExcelFilename
    
    If Workbooks.CanCheckOut(FileAddress) = True Then
        Workbooks.CheckOut ExcelFilename
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=ExcelFilename
    Else
        MsgBox "Unable to check out this document at this time."
    End If    
End Sub
```

Comment: At which line do you get the error? Why do you use `ExcelFilename` in `Workbooks.CheckOut ExcelFilename` and in `Workbooks.Open Filename:=ExcelFilename` instead of `FileAddress`

Comment: What is the type of path in `FileSharepointLocation` - https or a mapped/UNC drive?

Comment: @Storax

I'm getting error at the below line.

`If Workbooks.CanCheckOut(FileAddress) = True Then`  

I read few posts where some have used 'ExcelFilename in Workbooks.CheckOut ExcelFilename'  

You're right. I should use File address in place of file name (but getting error before that)  

@TimWilliams
The location is a https one

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this using the below code.

```
Sub ExcelUpdater()    
    FileSharepointLocation = Range("FileLocation").Value
    
    ExcelFilename = "Destination File.xlsb"
    
    FileAddress = FileSharepointLocation + "/" + ExcelFilename
    
    If Workbooks.CanCheckOut(FileAddress) = True Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=FileAddress
        Workbooks.CheckOut FileAddress        
    Else
        MsgBox "Unable to check out this document at this time."
    End If
    Workbooks(ExcelFilename).CheckIn SaveChanges:=True,Comments:="Changes in..."

End Sub
```