# Copy Data from one workbook to a shared workbook in sharepoint VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint-online

I have code which appends data into an excel workbook in sharepoint. It works fine for me, but when multiple users try to send data to the shared workbook, sometimes the data that the first user sends gets overwritten by the second user.

My code looks for the last data row inside the shared workbook, and pastes the data the user wants to send into the next row which is free. So basically the problem is, that for some reason my code miscalculates the last row in the shared workbook which leads to data overwrite.

In other words, users1 sends data1 and user2 sends data2. I see how data1 was sent to the sharedworkbook and appended to the next free rows. After around 5 seconds, data2 overwrites the data1 row.

This is the code i wrote. At first I thought it's a onedrive synchronisation problem, because the targetworkbook was initially on one drive. So I tried to fix the error by delaying the program so that one drive has time to synchronise. I also tried to implement a sort of "semaphore", by flagging the O1 cell in the target file. With this i wanted to not allow two users to send data at the same time as I thought that this was the cause of my overwrite problem.

The targetworkbook  is now in a normal microsoft teams/sharepoint folder without any onedrive connection and the error still occurs.

I want to add that this only happens when multiple users send data to the workbook (seemingly in a short timespan). When i tested it on my own, my data was  always appended in the correct row and it never overwrote previous data sent by me

```
Sub send_data()
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet


''col E, A, B doesn't need to be  copied
Columns("E").ClearContents
Columns("A").ClearContents
Columns("B").ClearContents
Dim targetColumn As Range
Set targetColumn = Columns("E")
With targetColumn.Interior
.Pattern = xlSolid
.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192)
End With



lstRow = fn_LastRow(ActiveSheet)

LstCol = fn_LastColumn(ActiveSheet)


'if targetworkbook is already opened:
On Error Resume Next
Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks("target.xlsm")
On Error GoTo 0 



Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If targetWorkbook Is Nothing Then
Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("sharepointlink")
End If





If targetWorkbook Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Target not found."
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
End If

''''this was an attempt to fix possible synchronisations issues by delaying the program
Dim attempts As Integer
attempts = 0
Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Sheets(1)

If IsEmpty(targetSheet.Range("O1").Value) Then
 targetSheet.Range("O1").Value = "Flag"
Else
 Do While Not IsEmpty(targetSheet.Range("O1").Value) And attempts < 20
  attempts = attempts + 1
  Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
  Loop
End If

If attempts = 20 Then
MsgBox "Please try again later"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub

Else
targetSheet.Range("O1").Value = "Flag"
End If
''''''this was an attempt to fix possible synchronisations issues



DstCol = fn_LastColumn(targetSheet)
LstRow_Dest = fn_LastRow(targetSheet)




SrcRng.Copy


targetSheet.Range("A" & LstRow_Dest + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Worksheets(targetSheet.Name).Range("A" & (LstRow_Dest + 1)).PasteSpecial

Application.CutCopyMode = False


SrcRng.ClearContents
'SrcRng.ClearFormats

targetSheet.Range("O1").Value = ""

targetWorkbook.Save

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

targetWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True

Set targetWorkbook = Nothing
Set targetSheet = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

```
Function fn_LastRow(ByVal Sht As Worksheet)


    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    lRow = Sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    Do While Application.CountA(Sht.Rows(lRow)) = 0 And lRow <> 1
        lRow = lRow - 1
    Loop
    fn_LastRow = lRow


End Function

Function fn_LastColumn(ByVal Sht As Worksheet)

    Dim lastCol As Long
    lastCol = Sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
    lCol = Sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
    Do While Application.CountA(Sht.Columns(lCol)) = 0 And lCol <> 1
        lCol = lCol - 1
    Loop
    fn_LastColumn = lCol

End Function
```

Comment: Sharepoint has its own semaphore system described in this post ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69435226/excel-macro-to-check-out-from-onedrive-sharepoint